# In WordPress how can I add text next to the Page tile, with (no title) as the title, in admin panel?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

How can I add this text next to Page titles in the WordPress Admin panel? I've searched high and low and no one seems to have a correct answer.

[image: Sample image of text after title in admin area]

I also found this snippet on GitHub but it seems to be based on the Page title name not the post ID or something else. If I have multiple pages that have no title ie. "(no-title)" this snippet cannot be used.

```
add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'ecs_add_post_state', 10, 2 );
function ecs_add_post_state( $post_states, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_name == 'edit-profile' ) {
        $post_states[] = 'Profile edit page';
    }
    return $post_states;
}
```

The class is "post-state". I would like to know how to add this text to pages based on the post ID or something other than the page title because some of my pages have no title, therefore displays "(no title)".

An example of this text is the WordPress "Home - Front Page" or the "- Privacy Policy Page". The code below is the html in the admin panel for the Home page row. The text that follows: "- Front Page" which is what I wish to add, is within the span tag at the end of the code below.

```
<tr id="post-2" class="iedit author-self level-0 post-2 type-page status-publish hentry">
            <th scope="row" class="check-column">           <label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-2">
                                                                                Select Home         </label>
            <input id="cb-select-2" type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="2">
            <div class="locked-indicator">
                <span class="locked-indicator-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">
                “Home” is locked                </span>
            </div>
            </th><td class="title column-title has-row-actions column-primary page-title" data-colname="Title"><div class="locked-info"><span class="locked-avatar"></span> <span class="locked-text"></span></div>
<strong><a class="row-title" href="https://test.winningsportsplays.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&amp;action=edit" aria-label="“Home” (Edit)">Home</a> — <span class="post-state">Front Page</span></strong>
```

Comment: The `$post` object in your `ecs_add_post_state` contains the ID of the post which you can access like this: `$post->ID`. So, changing `if( $post->post_name == 'edit-profile' ) {` into `if( $post->ID == YOUR-ID-HERE ) {` will let you do whatever you need to do when a given post ID matches the condition. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @cabrerahector I was so close. Amazing! Thank you! I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and include your solution here, maybe someone will benefit from reading your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cabrerahector Thank you!

```
add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'ecs_add_post_state', 10, 2 );
function ecs_add_post_state( $post_states, $post ) {
    if( $post->ID == YOUR-ID-HERE ) {
        $post_states[] = 'Profile edit page';
    }
    return $post_states;
}
```